# Why does my barplot turn into a line graph when I try to create a discontinuous axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, data-visualization, yaxis

I'm trying to create a discontinuous y-axis on a bar plot. I'm able to break the axis as I want but the resulting graph looks like a line plot of my data instead of the original bar plot I had. In the attached image, I want the bar plot on the top axis to appear on the axis frames of the bottom graph.

Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[PURO, MYC, HRAS, CYCD, AURKB], index=Phenotype)
df.plot.bar()

plt.xlabel('Phenotype (# of poles, total # of centrioles)')
plt.ylabel('# of cells')

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, sharey=False)

ax.plot(df)
ax2.plot(df)


ax.set_ylim(40,100) 
ax2.set_ylim(0,20)

ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.xaxis.tick_top()
ax.tick_params(labeltop='off')  # don't put tick labels at the top
ax2.xaxis.tick_bottom()

plt.show()
```

[Resulting plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUUtL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you first plot a bar plot and then twice the DataFrames using `ax.plot()` and `ax2.plot()` which simply plots connecting lines.

*Solution*: Delete the following line

```
df.plot.bar()
```

and replace `ax.plot(df)` and `ax2.plot(df)` by

```
df.plot.bar(ax=ax) 
df.plot.bar(ax=ax2)
```

Below is a minimal working answer (excluding imports) for you using a *dummy DataFrame*. Same will work for your case too.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

df = pd.DataFrame({'count': {0: 88, 1: 67, 2: 10, 3: 16, 4: 18}}).reset_index()
fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, sharey=False)

df.plot.bar(x='index', y='count', legend=False, ax=ax)
df.plot.bar(x='index', y='count', legend=False, ax=ax2)

ax.set_ylim(50,100) 
ax2.set_ylim(0,20)

ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.xaxis.tick_top()
ax.tick_params(labeltop='off')  # don't put tick labels at the top
ax2.xaxis.tick_bottom()
```

You can add the diagonals/small lines to highlight the broken lines by just copying the lines from [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html) official example

**Output**

[image]